# Can not find PlayEbean Play 2.5.x

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, error-handling, sbt, ebean

i am using the Play Java Starter Example 2.5.x from the Play Framework page this is my plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")
```

this is my build.sbt

```
name := """play-java"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava,PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
libraryDependencies += filters
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  evolutions
)
```

In application.conf:

```
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

when trying to run the application i always get:

```
error: not found: value PlayEbean lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean) ^ sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression [error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression Invalid response.
```

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching i solved it the problem was that i did not put the

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")
```

in the correct file.